# Diferença entre as funções 'click', 'bind', 'live', 'delegate', 'trigger' e 'on'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Dei uma pesquisada mas não há uma listagem de comparação entre as funções abaixo:

```
$().click(fn)
$().bind('click', fn)
$().live('click', fn)
$().delegate(selector, 'click', fn)
$().trigger('click') 
$().on('click', selector, fn);
```

Como todas as funções acima funcionam exatamente?
Quais devem ser priorizadas em quais situações?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Todas estas funções estão relacionadas a eventos. Então precisamos entender alguns conceitos para ir adiante.

#### Event Phase

Quando um evento é emitido ele tem [3 fases](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-eventphase), um handler de evento pode saber em que fase está através da propriedade [`Event.eventPhase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase).
As fases são:

1. `CAPTURING_PHASE`: o evento é propagado do `window` até o elemento alvo do evento ([`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget))
2. `AT_TARGET`: o evento chegou no seu alvo
3. `BUBBLING_PHASE`: o evento é propagado de volta até `window`.

Estas fase podem ser melhor visualizadas na imagem a seguir ([fonte](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow)):

[image: Fases de propagação de um evento]

E agora você já sabe para que serve o parâmetro `useCapture` do método [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Syntax), por padrão o *handler* intercepta o evento na fase de *bubbling*, mas você pode alterar isso através deste parâmetro.  ;)

#### Delegation

Sabendo disso, agora precisamos entender o que significa delegar um evento ([este é um bom artigo para ajudar no entendimento](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)).

A delegação de eventos consiste em atribuir o *handler* de eventos de um elemento alvo a um elemento pai.
Ou seja, ao invés do *handler* do evento ser atribuído no elemento alvo e ser executado na fase `AT_TARGET`, ele vai ser atribuído para um elemento pai deste elemento alvo e vai ser executado na fase `CAPTURING_PHASE` ou `BUBBLING_PHASE`.

Qual a vantagem disso? A principal vantagem é que o elemento alvo não precisa existir ao atribuir o *handler* ao evento, apenas o elemento pai. Fazendo com que elementos inseridos dinamicamente na página reajam aos eventos delegados sem precisar atribuir um *handler* a cada um deles.

Um rápido exemplo para ilustrar como isso funciona:

```js
let pai = document.querySelector('#elemento-pai');

pai.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // #pai não é alvo, mas está interceptando o evento
  // na fase de bubbling
  if (event.target.classList.contains('elemento-alvo')) {
    event.target.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});

// adiciona itens dinamicamente à lista
let btn = document.querySelector('#add');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = "elemento-alvo";
  li.innerHTML = "Item dinâmico";
  pai.appendChild(li);
});
```

```css
.elemento-alvo.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="elemento-pai">
  <li class="elemento-alvo">Item</li>
  <li class="elemento-alvo">Item</li>
</ul>
<button id="add">+</button>
```

Agora que o conceito de delegação de eventos está mais claro, fica mais fácil explicar a pergunta.

Vamos começar dividindo os métodos em categorias (ou por funcionalidade, ou sei lá).

Vamos chamar de: **Escutar eventos**, **Emitir Eventos** e **Atalhos**.

---

1. **Escutar eventos**:

   - [bind](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) (descontinuado no jQuery 3.0): adiciona um *handler* para um evento no elemento (fase `AT_TARGET`).
   - [live](https://api.jquery.com/live/) (descontinuado no jQuery 1.7): adicionar um *handler* para um evento através de delegation. Porém o "elemento pai" é sempre `document`.
   - [delegate](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (descontinuado no jQuery 3.0, seu uso é desencorajado desde o jQuery 1.7): também adiciona um *handler* para um evento através de delegation, só que é possível escolher o "elemento pai".
   - [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/): é o método recomendado a ser usado, visto que ele faz o que todos os outros podem fazer.

     Você pode atribuir *handler* para um evento diretamente no elemento. Ex.:

     ```
     $('#btn').on('click', myHandler)
     ```

     Ou delegar o evento:

     ```
     $('#elemento-pai').on('click', '.elemento-target', myHandler)
     ```
2. **Emitir eventos**:

   - [trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/): é o métodos que você emite o evento para que os *handlers* sejam chamados.
3. **Atalhos**: São métodos para facilitar o uso de alguns métodos comumente utilizados. No geral `$elemento.evento(...)` é equivalente a `$elemento.on('evento', handler)` quando usado para escutar um evento ou `$elemento.trigger('evento')` quando é para emitir o evento.

   - [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/);

     ```
     $elemento.click(function(){});
     // mesmo que
     $elemento.on('click', function(){});

     $elemento.click();
     // mesmo que
     $elemento.trigger('click');
     ```
   - [focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/);

     ```
     $elemento.focus(function(){});
     // mesmo que
     $elemento.on('focus', function(){});

     $elemento.focus();
     // mesmo que
     $elemento.trigger('focus');
     ```
   - [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/);

     ```
     $elemento.blur(function(){});
     // mesmo que
     $elemento.on('blur', function(){});

     $elemento.blur();
     // mesmo que
     $elemento.trigger('blur');
     ```
   - [outros eventos](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/)...

Comment: +1, muito mais detalhada que minha resposta que escrevi com pressa :)

Comment: Depois que entende é fácil, mas é difícil de explicar. Eu sabia as diferenças mas quando comecei a escrever e demorar demais ia lançar uma versão reduzida. Aí você já tinha postado sua resposta e decidi seguir na labuta. :D

Answer (score 4):

Os métodos `live` e `delegate` são formas antigas de delegação de eventos, e já foram removidas da biblioteca. Atualmente se deve fazer delegação com a sintaxe:

```
$('seletor').on('evento', 'outro-seletor', callback);
```

Já `$('seletor').click(fn)` é simplesmente um atalho para `$('seletor').on('click', fn)`. O `bind` também é uma forma antiga que foi removida da biblioteca, e substituída pelo `.on`.

O `.trigger` faz o contrário do que todos esses outros métodos. Como o nome diz, ele dispara um evento. Já `.on` e atalhos como `.click` tratam eventos disparados por terceiros.