# Pegar text de um select dentro de um foreach javascript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde

Pessoal tenho um select que adiciona dinamicamente linha a linha dentro de uma tabela, porem meu código só pega o text da primeira linha. Gostaria de pegar o text de acordo com a linha e passar para um input hidden.

**MEU SELECT DINÂMICO**

```
  '<td>'+
      '<select name="idcentrocusto[]" id="selectOption" onchange="getSelect();">'+
        '<option value="">Selecione Centro Custos...</option>'+
        '<?php foreach ($centrocustos as $c){?>'+
        '<option value="<?php echo $c->idcentrocusto?>">'+
          '<?php echo $c->centrocusto?>'+
        '</option>'+
        '<?php } ?>'+
      '</select>'+
    '</td>'+
```

**FUNÇÃO AO ALTERAR O SELECT**

```
function getSelect() {
 var vai=$('#selectOption option:selected').html();
 $('#centrocusto').attr('value', vai);
}
```

**ERRO**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**TABELA (ESTA DENTRO DE UM MODAL DE BUSCA)**

```
  <table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Un</th>
        <th>Produto</th>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Qnt*</th>
        <th>Delhamento Produto</th>
        <th>...</th>


      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php foreach ($produtos as $produto){?>
      <tr>
        <td id="id"><?php echo $produto->idproduto?></td>
        <td id="un"><?php echo $produto->un?></td>
        <td id="produto"><?php echo $produto->produto?></td>
        <td id="codigo"><?php echo $produto->codigo?></td>
        <td><input style="max-width: 55px" class="form-control" id="qnt" type="text" name="qnt[]"  onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"></td>
        <td><input style="width: 100%" class="form-control" id="detalhe" type="text" name="detalhe"></td>
        <td><button class="add glyphicon glyphicon-plus img-circle text-primary btn-icon"></button></td>
      </tr>

      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**TABELA PAGINA PRINCIPAL (RECEBE DADOS DA BUSCA)**

```
<table id="tab" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th id="tab_cab">Produto</th>
                        <th id="tab_cab">Qnt</th>
                        <th id="tab_cab">Detalhar Produto</th>
                        <th id="tab_cab">Centro de Custo</th>
                        <th id="tab_cab">...</th>

                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                   <tbody id="mytbody">

                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                         <th>Total de Itens: <span id="counter"></span></th>
                         <th style="text-align: center;"> <span id="total"></span></th>
                         <th></th>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
```

Comment: `id` é único, não pode ser repetido. Seria como você procurar uma pessoa por CPF ou algum número de documento e existirem várias pessoas com a mesma **ID**entificação. Sugiro que use classes para fazer isso, dessa maneira.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Fernado. Como seria isso so substituir o id pela classe?

Comment: Estou formulando uma resposta pra explicar melhor. É só aguardar um pouco. =D

Comment: Você poderia colocar a estrutura de toda a tabela por favor?

Comment: Pronto ja postei, essas dados vai para o  <tbody id="mytbody">

Comment: Basta trocar o id por class, por exemplo: `class="tab_cab"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) deve ser único em um documento, se você precisa usar vários elementos com o mesmo `id` provavelmente o que você quer é usar [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class).

Elaborei um exemplo onde uso classes para selecionar o `input` que está no mesmo `tr` do `select` clicado usando o método [`jQuery.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) juntamente com o método [`jQuery.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) e a propriedade [`HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) (somente-leitura).

Como os `<select>` são inseridos dinamicamente você pode fazer uso de [delegação de eventos](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). Explico melhor sobre delegação de eventos na pergunta: [Diferença entre as funções 'click', 'bind', 'live', 'delegate', 'trigger' e 'on'?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333053/6333).

---

Exemplo:

```js
var $tbody = $('#table-body')
var row_template =  `
<tr>
  <td>
    <select name="idcentrocusto[]" class="select-custos">
      <option value="">Selecione Centro Custos...</option>
      <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
      <option value="2">Opção 2</option>
      <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="custo" readonly>
  </td>
</tr>
`

// Ao clicar no botão, adiciona mais uma linha
$('#add-row').on('click', function() {
  $tbody.append(row_template)
})

// Delega o evento de change dos selects ao <tbody>
$tbody.on('change', '.select-custos', function () {
  // Pega o texto da opção escolhida
  var selected_text = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
  // Pega o input correspondente ao select clicado
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.custo').val(selected_text)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add-row">Add</button> <br>

<hr>

<table>
  <tbody id="table-body">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ótima resposta @fernando :D +1

Comment: show de bola Ferndando, porem o input vai na mesma linha com o select, como seria sendo assim?

Comment: Sempre que eu tenho que falar sobre delegação de eventos apontar para aquela resposta. Passei muito tempo escrevendo ela. É mais fácil linkar do que explicar tudo de novo.. hahaha

Comment: Cada linha vai ter seu input hidden com o valor do select?

Comment: Sim , isso mesmo. E ele vai receber o text do select.

Comment: Hmmm.. entendi. Vou alterar a resposta

Comment: Então você não preciso daquele input com os ids selecionados né?

Comment: Resposta alterada. A maior diferença aí é como fazer o traverse do DOM com o `jQuery.closest()` e `jQuery.find()`

Comment: Deu certinho. Agradeço muito.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
'<td>'+
  '<select name="idcentrocusto[]" onchange="getSelect(this);">'+
    '<option value="">Selecione Centro Custos...</option>'+
    '<?php foreach ($centrocustos as $c){?>'+
    '<option value="<?php echo $c->idcentrocusto?>">'+
      '<?php echo $c->centrocusto?>'+
    '</option>'+
    '<?php } ?>'+
  '</select>'+
'</td>'+


function getSelect(obj) {
 var vai= obj.value;
 $('#centrocusto').attr('value', vai);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo Retorno Alvaro mas esta mudando apenas o primeiro, coloquei o input visivel para testar, veja na imagem.