# Ajuda para capturar mudança em campo checkbox

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código que busca o produto e cria a linha na tabela da forma que quero e depois armazeno os dados num Json para ser enviado por post.

Funciona somente quando insiro um novo produto. Mas eu precisava armazenar o Json sempre que eu marcar um checkbox que crio com o jquery. Mas não estou encontrando o comando que faço isso. Já tentei todo tipo de comando. Até teste no console para mostrar uma mensagem quando clico no checkbox, mas não mostra mensagem alguma. Alguém pode me ajudar em como capturar a mudança no checkbox?

já tentei `$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", armazenarCampos);` Mas não atualiza.

Segue o código que gera a tabela:

```
var codigo = $("#codigo_barras");
codigo.on("keydown",function(e){
      if(e.which == 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.get("controle/pedido-troca-pendente-busca-produto.php?codigo="+codigo.val(),geraLinha);
      }
});

function geraLinha(data){
  var produto = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  if(produto.id_produto!=0){
      var linha  = $("<tr>").addClass("linha");
      var colunaProduto = $("<td>").text(produto.produto);
      var colunaTamanho = $("<td>").text(produto.tamanho);
      var colunaPreco = $("<td>").text(produto.preco);
      var colunaUsuario = $("<td>").text(produto.usuario);
      var colunaDefeito = $("<td>");
      var colunaRemove = $("<td>");

      var campoIdProduto = $("<input>").addClass("id_produto").attr("type","hidden").attr("value",produto.id_produto);
      var campoTamanho = $("<input>").addClass("tamanho").attr("type","hidden").attr("value",produto.tamanho);
      var campoPreco = $("<input>").addClass("preco").attr("type","hidden").attr("value",produto.preco);
      var campoTipoCobranca =$("<input>").addClass("tipo_cobranca").attr("type","hidden").attr("value",produto.tipo_cobranca);
      var campoIdTabela = $("<input>").addClass("id_tabela").attr("type","hidden").attr("value",produto.id_tabela);
      var campoDefeito = $("<input>").addClass("defeito").attr("type","checkbox").attr("value","true");

      var link = $("<a>").addClass("botao-remover").addClass("btn").addClass("btn-danger").addClass("glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-trash").attr("href","#");

      colunaDefeito.append(campoDefeito);
      colunaRemove.append(link);

      linha.append(colunaProduto);
      linha.append(colunaTamanho);
      linha.append(colunaPreco);
      linha.append(colunaUsuario);
      linha.append(colunaDefeito);
      linha.append(colunaRemove);

      linha.append(campoIdProduto);
      linha.append(campoTamanho);
      linha.append(campoPreco);
      linha.append(campoTipoCobranca);
      linha.append(campoIdTabela);

      $("#troca-pendente").append(linha);
      codigo.val("");

  }else{
    $("#erro").toggle();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#erro").toggle();
    },2000);
  }

  armazenarCampos();
}

function armazenarCampos() {
    if($('.linha').length>0){
    var produtos = [];

        $('.linha').each(function(){
            var id_produto = $(this).find(".id_produto").val();
            var tamanho = $(this).find(".tamanho").val();
            var preco = $(this).find(".preco").val();
            var tipo_cobranca = $(this).find(".tipo_cobranca").val();
            var id_tabela = $(this).find(".id_tabela").val();
            if($(this).find("input:checked").val()){
              var defeito = 1;
            }else{
              var defeito = 0;
            }

            var produto = {
              id_produto:id_produto,
              tamanho:tamanho,
              preco:preco,
              tipo_cobranca:tipo_cobranca,
              id_tabela:id_tabela,
              defeito:defeito
            };
          produtos.push(produto);
        });

        $("#produtos-troca").attr("name","produtos-troca").attr("value",JSON.stringify(produtos));
    }
}
```

html gerado pelo jquery:

```
<tbody id="troca-pendente">
    <tr class="linha">
        <td>165 Caramelo</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>39.90</td>
        <td>Admin</td>
        <td><input class="defeito" type="checkbox" value="true"></td>
        <td><a class="botao-remover btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon- 
            trash" href="#"></a></td>
        <input class="id_produto" type="hidden" value="7">
        <input class="tamanho" type="hidden" value="34"><input class="preco" 
               type="hidden" value="39.90">
        <input class="tipo_cobranca" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input class="id_tabela" type="hidden" value="3">
    </tr>
    <tr class="linha">
         <td>01 Preto</td>
         <td>38</td>
         <td>39.90</td>
         <td>Admin</td>
         <td><input class="defeito" type="checkbox" value="true"></td>
         <td><a class="botao-remover btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon- 
             trash" href="#"></a></td>
         <input class="id_produto" type="hidden" value="8">
         <input class="tamanho" type="hidden" value="38">
         <input class="preco" type="hidden" value="39.90">
         <input class="tipo_cobranca" type="hidden" value="1">
         <input class="id_tabela" type="hidden" value="3">
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: crie uma classe no checkbox para acessar por $('.sua_classe') e depois use o evento change $('.sua_classe').on('change', function(){...});

Comment: $('.defeito').on('change',function(){
  console.log("clicou");
}); e não funciona. Não mostra nada no log

Comment: deu o log fazendo isso?

Comment: Não mostra nada. Será que tem a ver com estar dentro de um <td>?

Comment: Entendi, vc esta criando o checkbox dinamicante. Então vc tem que atrelar o evento ao checkbox depois de cria-lo. tente assim $('.defeito').bind('change', function (){...});

Comment: Anexei o html gerado no post. Mesmo o bind não deu certo

Comment: vc está setando o evento depois de os inputs estarem criados?

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua pergunta, mas coloquei $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", function(){  console.log("entrou");} ); no final do codigo jquery

Comment: Resolvido com a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está gerando os checkboxes dinamicamente, quando você executa `$("input[type=checkbox]").on( "click", armazenarCampos)` eles ainda não existem.

Então você estará escutando o evento `click` apenas dos `input[type=checkbox]` que já estiverem na tela, e não dos que existirão no futuro.

Para trabalhar com eventos em elementos dinâmicos existe uma técnica chamada Delegação de Eventos, que explico com mais profundidade na pergunta: [Diferença entre as funções 'click', 'bind', 'live', 'delegate', 'trigger' e 'on'?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333053/6333).

Para usar delegação de eventos no jQuery basta usar o método [`jQuery.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) fazendo com que o handler de eventos fique num elemento pai, que já está no HTML, escute eventos dos elementos filhos.

No seu caso pode-se utilizar:

```
$("#troca-pendente").on("click", ".defeito", armazenarCampos);
// ^ Elemento pai                 ^ Target do evento
```

---

Exemplo sem delegação:

```js
let template = `
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox dinâmico
</label>
`;

$('#add').on('click', function() {
    $(document.body).append(template);
});

// Handler de eventos no próprio input
$('input').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});
```

```css
label {
    display: block;
}

label.active {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='add'>Add</button>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox já existente
</label>
```

---

Exemplo com delegação:

```js
let template = `
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox dinâmico
</label>
`;

$('#add').on('click', function() {
    $(document.body).append(template);
});

// Handler de eventos em um elemento pai (delegação de eventos)
$('body').on('change', 'input', function() {
    $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});
```

```css
label {
    display: block;
}

label.active {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='add'>Add</button>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox já existente
</label>
```

Comment: Entendi. Então enquanto monto dinamicamente a tabela e já teria que colocar o evento no checkbox. Fiz assim:       linha.find(".defeito").click(armazenarCampos); dentro da função de gerarLinha() e funcionou agora. Obrigado

Comment: Pelo contrário, isso não seria performático. Você teria que usar delegação de eventos, dessa maneira um elemento teria o handler do evento para todos os checkbox que estão na tela e os futuros.

Comment: Já tentou `$("#troca-pendente").on("click", ".defeito", armazenarCampos);` como coloquei na resposta?

Comment: Deu certo do jeito que você disse com esse comando. Desculpe a afobação. Acho que vou ter que estudar um pouco mais de Jquery e seletores css. Porque eu precisava resolver isso urgente. Obrigado pela disposição, ajudou bastante. Abraço.

Comment: Leia a minha explicação sobre delegação de eventos que eu linkei na resposta. Lá está bem detalhado pra você entender.