# Usando duas funções no mesmo OnClick

Tags: javascript, funções

Eu tenho duas funções JavaScript que são acionadas pelo mesmo botão, uma que é responsável pelas validações e outra que faz avançar a página.

Eu não consigo juntar essas funções e nem alterar a que avança de página, pois ela é feita pelo próprio framework da empresa, eu consigo mexer somente na função de validação.

O problema é que mesmo inserindo `return null` na função da validação, a função de avançar a página é acionada, ou seja, o formulário é validado mas a página avança mesmo assim.

Por motivos de confidenciabilidade eu não posso mostrar o código, mas espero que tenha ficado claro a situação.

Então, se eu tenho a situação a seguir:

```
onClick="functionValidacao(); functionAvancarPagina();"
```

Como "anular" a `functionAvancarPagina()` caso a `functionValidacao()` aponte erros?

Comment: Luiz, alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Em caso afirmativo, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis :-) E se nenhuma respondeu/resolveu, vc pode comentar e/ou se for o caso, [edit] a pergunta com mais detalhes :-)

Answer (score 3):

Crie as duas functions, após isso dentro da função de validação, você faz uma validação(IF), se ocorrer tudo certo, voçê dispara a function de avançar. Espero ter ajudado !

```
function validar(){
    if(camposValidadosCorretamente == true){ // se a validação está correta
        this.irParaProximaPagina(); // chama função e vai para a próxima página
    }
}

function irParaProximaPagina(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oi Leroy! Podes juntar um exemplo de código? Nós ajudamos a formatar se fôr preciso

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode interceptar o evento de click antes que ele chegue no botão, executar os testes que você precisa e decidir se deixa o evento chegar no botão ou não.

Para fazer isso você vai precisar entender como os eventos se propagam pelo DOM, [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333053/6333) tem uma explicação mais completa, mas um resumo seria:

1. O usuário clica no botão
2. O evento `click` propaga do `window` até o `button`. (Capture Phase)
3. O evento chega no `button`. (Target Phase)
4. O evento "borbulha" de volta ao `window`. (Bubbling Phase)

Talvez fique mais fácil de entender com a imagem abaixo:

[image: Fases da propagação de eventos no DOM]

---

Dito isso, você poderia escutar o evento `click` no pai do `button` na fase de captura (Capture Phase) e escolher se permite ou não que o evento propague até o `button`.

Para fazer isso basta usar o método [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) com o parâmetro `useCapture` como `true` para que o *handler* seja executado na Capture Phase.

```
btnParent.addEventListener('click', meuHandler, true);
```

Dentro de `meuHandler` você pode impedir que o evento chegue no botão utilizando o método [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Segue um exemplo dos conceitos explicados:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
var check = document.getElementById('check')
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper')

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('-> Esta função sai da página!')
})

wrapper.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (check.checked) {
    console.log('Evento de click cancelado...')
    event.stopPropagation()
  }
}, true)
```

```html
<span id="wrapper">
  <button id="btn">Click</button>
</span>

<label>
  <input id="check" type="checkbox"> Cancelar envio
</label>
```