# o que é captura, propagação e borbulhamento de eventos? Um ou mais termos são a mesma coisa? Exemplos!

Tags: javascript

Já li alguns post´s sobre o assunto, mas ainda não está claro os conceitos (e principalmente exemplos, simples) sobre propagação, borbulhamento e lista de eventos. Dia desses, precisei usar event.preventDefault e me deparei com tal questao.

Comment: [Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/333005/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-as-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-click-bind-live-delegate-trigger-e-on/333053#333053) eu explico as fases de eventos e propagação... dá uma olhada, quem sabe te ajude a entender.

Comment: @fernandosavio essa resposta é excelente, `+1`. Mas acho é mais relacionada com esta pergunta do que com a outra... :)

Comment: @Sergio muito obrigado, deu trabalho! hahaha. Eu não marquei como duplicada porque a resposta podia esclarecer melhor o conceito mas realmente, não responde a pergunta. :D

Comment: Só deixei como um "material extra"

Comment: fernandosavio... entao, basicamente, borbulhamento é o mesmo que propagação, correto? Quanto ao  `preventDefault`, já ficou bem claro, assim como o `stopPropagation`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `.preventDefault()` e borbulhamento são coisas diferentes. O `.preventDefault()` faz com que uma ação esperada/natural do browser não aconteça e o `stopPropagation()` trava o borbulhamento.

### `.preventDefault()`

Se clicares numa âncora como `<a href="http://google.com">` o esperado/natural é ser redirecionado para o site do Google. Usando o `.preventDefault()` podes impedir isso. Por exemplo, repara como podes distinguir quais as âncoras devem ter o comportamento natural:

```js
const ancoras = document.querySelectorAll('a');
ancoras.forEach(a => a.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (a.href.includes('stack')) {
    // aqui vamos parar todos os cliques para sites com "stack" no nome
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}));
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
```

### `.stopPropagation()`

Quando clicas num elemento o evento vem do window/document, desce até ao elemento e depois volta a subir no DOM. Nesse "borbulhamento" podes parar o evento de subir no DOM com o `.stopPropagation()`.  Dá uma olhada ao exemplo em baixo:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
divs.forEach(a => a.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(`A borbulhar de ${e.target.id} para ${a.id}`);
  if (a.id === 'B') {
    // aqui vamos parar o borbulhamento para nunca chegar a <div id="A">
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

}));
```

```css
div {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  transition: background .3s;
}

div:hover {
  background: rgba(50, 50, 50, .3);
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">
    <div id="C">
      <div id="D">Clica numa das divs...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```