# Elementos novos inseridos programaticamente não possuem os event listeners, mesmo tendo exatamente o mesmo conteúdo

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Tenho este código:

```js
let app = document.querySelector('.app');
let button = document.querySelector('.btn');
let newButton = `<button class="btn">Clique-me</button>`;

button.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
   alert('removido');
   app.innerHTML = '';
   app.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newButton);
});
```

```html
<div class="app">
    <button class="btn">Clique-me</button>  
</div>
```

Ao clicar no botão, o `alert` só é exibido na primeira vez.

Por que exatamente o evento não funciona de novo? Já que estou criando um elemento exatamente igual ao primeiro? E o que posso fazer para que sempre que eu adicionar tal elemento ele possa ser ouvido?

Answer (score 4):

Apesar do novo botão ser um elemento com a mesma tag, classe e conteúdo, ele **não é o mesmo elemento**, e portanto ele não tem o evento de clique que o elemento original tinha.

Veja aqui como o botão muda depois que você o remove e adiciona outro:

```js
let app = document.querySelector('.app');
let button = document.querySelector('.btn');
let newButton = '<button class="btn">Clique-me</button>';

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // antes de remover, o botão dentro de "app" é o mesmo que "button"
    console.log(app.querySelector('button') === button); // true
    app.innerHTML = '';
    app.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',newButton);
    // depois de remover e adicionar outro, o botão dentro de "app" não é mais o mesmo que "button"
    console.log(app.querySelector('button') === button); // false
});
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <button class="btn">Clique-me</button>  
</div>
```

Depois de clicar no botão, ele vai mostrar no console `true` (pois o botão que está dentro da `div` é o original) e depois `false` (pois o novo botão que foi inserido não é mais o mesmo elemento - ou seja, se clicar na segunda vez ele já não imprime mais nada, pois o novo botão não tem nenhum evento de clique associado).

Segundo a [documentação de `insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), é feito o *parsing* do HTML e os nós resultantes deste *parsing* são inseridos no [DOM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/112052). O que acontece é que esses nós novos não tem nenhuma relação com os anteriores (mesmo que o conteúdo do HTML seja idêntico).

---

## Solução

Em vez de adicionar o evento no botão, uma alternativa é usar [*event delegation*](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) e colocar o evento na `div`:

```js
let app = document.querySelector('.app');
let button = document.querySelector('.btn');
let newButton = '<button class="btn">Clique-me</button>';

app.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const element = e.target; // pega o elemento que foi clicado
    // verifica se o elemento clicado é o botão que tem a classe btn
    if (element.nodeName == 'BUTTON' && element.classList.contains('btn')) {
        alert('removido');
        app.innerHTML = newButton;
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <button class="btn">Clique-me</button>  
</div>
```

Ou seja, o evento de clique é para toda a `div` (inclusive qualquer elemento dentro dela), mas no *callback* eu verifico se o elemento clicado é o botão. Para saber melhor como funciona o *event delegation*, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333053/112052).

Note também que nem precisa de `insertAdjacentHTML`, pois antes você seta o `innerHTML` para a string vazia, e isso faz com que todo o conteúdo da `div` seja apagado (`insertAdjacentHTML` faz mais sentido se você quisesse manter os elementos da `div` e quisesse inserir o novo na posição específica, mas como a `div` estará vazia, não faz diferença). Sendo assim, é mais fácil simplesmente substituir o `innerHTML` diretamente.

---

#### Alternativa

Uma alternativa é adicionar o *listener* no novo elemento. Em vez de criar o elemento como uma string, pode ser feito assim:

```js
function removeBotaoCriaOutro() {
    const novo = document.createElement('button');
    novo.classList.add('btn');
    novo.textContent = 'Clique-me';
    // *** adicionar o evento no novo botão ***
    novo.addEventListener('click', removeBotaoCriaOutro);

    alert('removido');
    app.innerHTML = '';
    app.appendChild(novo); // como o div está vazio, pode adicionar assim
}

let app = document.querySelector('.app');
let button = document.querySelector('.btn');

button.addEventListener('click', removeBotaoCriaOutro);
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <button class="btn">Clique-me</button>  
</div>
```

Mas se quiser manter o novo botão como string, também pode ser:

```js
function removeBotaoCriaOutro() {
    let novo = document.createElement('template');
    novo.innerHTML = '<button class="btn">Clique-me</button>';
    novo = novo.content.firstChild;
    novo.addEventListener('click', removeBotaoCriaOutro);

    alert('removido');
    app.innerHTML = '';
    app.appendChild(novo); // como o div está vazio, pode adicionar assim
}

let app = document.querySelector('.app');
let button = document.querySelector('.btn');

button.addEventListener('click', removeBotaoCriaOutro);
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <button class="btn">Clique-me</button>  
</div>
```

Ou ainda, colocar o evento `onclick` na própria string:

```js
function removeBotaoCriaOutro() {
    alert('removido');
    app.innerHTML = '<button class="btn" onclick="removeBotaoCriaOutro()">Clique-me</button>';
}

let app = document.querySelector('.app');
let button = document.querySelector('.btn');

button.addEventListener('click', removeBotaoCriaOutro);
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <button class="btn">Clique-me</button>  
</div>
```

Mas me parece um trabalho desnecessário ter que adicionar o evento toda hora, pois na minha opinião, usar *event delegation* é uma solução bem mais simples para este caso, já que basta adicionar o evento uma vez na `div` e ela cuida de verificar se o elemento clicado é o botão que queremos. Desta forma, quaisquer elementos novos que forem adicionados já "ganham de graça" o *event handler* da `div`.

Mas claro que o que é "melhor" varia conforme o caso. Por exemplo, se a `div` tiver muitos elementos e você só quer o evento de clique em um deles, aí talvez valha a pena adicionar o evento somente no elemento específico, mas se tem vários elementos que podem ser removidos e adicionados dinamicamente e todos respondem ao mesmo evento, pode ser mais simples usar *event delegation*.

---

<sup>Eu só questiono a utilidade de remover um elemento para adicionar outro idêntico logo em seguida (se foi para fins de aprendizado, ainda vai...)</sup>

Comment: Boa resposta. Na minha opinião adicionar o evento diretamente no novo elemento é melhor e na maior parte das vezes evita testes complicados de se o `target` é o elemento que nós queremos, para além de garantir que não executamos handlers de click desnecessários (por exemplo areas vazias do div que não tem botões).

Comment: @Isac Realmente, o que é "melhor" varia muito conforme a situação e eu me referia ao caso específico. Editei para deixar isso mais claro, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

continuei pesquisando e na comunidade em inglês encontrei algumas soluções, segue a que eu iriei usar:

```js
let app = document.querySelector('.app');
let button = document.querySelector('.btn');
let newButton = `<button class="btn">Clique-me</button>`;

button.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
     app.innerHTML = '';
   console.log('clear app');
   app.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',newButton);
   console.log('add event');
   addEvent('.btn','click'); 
});

let addEvent = (target, event) => {
    let element = document.querySelector(target);
  element.addEventListener(event, (e)=>{
    console.log('new element with event');
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
<button class="btn">Clique-me</button>  
</div>
```

Desse jeito a cada elemento que inserirmos dinamicamente já adicionaremos o evento junto! Valeu \o

Comment: Thayllon, existem maneiras mais sucintas de se fazer isso. O Stack Overflow em Portguês tem respostas para esses problemas se você procurar, e [aqui tem um link de exemplo de como utilizar _delegated_](https://jsfiddle.net/rcs4ok9t/)