# Por que o addEventListener não funciona com innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Eu tenho um `input type="text"` e um botão que colocará o texto escrito no `input` em uma `li`.

Acontece que ao utilizar o `innerHTML` para inserir o texto do `input`, o `addEventListener` que eu havia criado para que quando clicasse numa `li` para que ficasse com um background vermelho parou de funcionar:

```js
// POR QUE AO ADICIONAR NOVA LI O ADDEVENTLISTENER NÃO FUNCIONOU?

var $List = document.getElementById('listContainer');
var $lis = $List.getElementsByTagName('li');
var $addItem = document.querySelector('button');
var input = document.getElementById('addText');

$addItem.addEventListener('click', add);
input.addEventListener('keyup', enter);

for(var i=0; i<$lis.length; i++){
    $lis[i].addEventListener('click', feitoOuNao);
}


function feitoOuNao(){
    this.classList.toggle('done');
}         
function enter(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        add();
    }
}            
function add(){
    if(input.value){
        $List.innerHTML += '<li>'+ input.value +'</li>';
        addFocus();
    } else{
        addFocus();
        throw new Error('coloque um item válido')
    }                
    function addFocus(){
        input.focus();
        input.value = null;
    }
}
```

```css
.done{
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="addText">
<button>Adicionar Item</button>
<ol id="listContainer">
    <li>Varrer casa</li>
    <li>Lavar louça</li>
    <li>Fazer comida</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Os eventos não serão adicionados automaticamente ao usar createElement ou criar com innerHTML, para que funcione você teria que checar se o evento já existe, melhor seria usar createElement para isso e adicionar o evento a cada novo elemento, você também pode resolver isso com [delegação do evento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) (o click funcionará, mas note que existem eventos que não são [bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture) e portanto não seriam capturáveis)

Answer (score 1):

Quando você faz o `for` em `$lis`, ele só chama `addEventListener` nos elementos `li` que existiam inicialmente.

Quando um novo `li` é adicionado, ele não ganha automaticamente o *listener* que os outros já tinham. Então você tem que adicioná-lo manualmente. Só que aí não seria mais com `innerHTML`, teria que ser algo mais "manual":

```js
var novoLi = document.createElement('li');
novoLi.addEventListener('click', feitoOuNao);
novoLi.textContent = input.value;
$List.appendChild(novoLi);
```

Ou seja, ficaria assim:

```js
var $List = document.getElementById('listContainer');
var $lis = $List.getElementsByTagName('li');
var $addItem = document.querySelector('button');
var input = document.getElementById('addText');

$addItem.addEventListener('click', add);
input.addEventListener('keyup', enter);

for(var i=0; i<$lis.length; i++){
    $lis[i].addEventListener('click', feitoOuNao);
}


function feitoOuNao(){
    this.classList.toggle('done');
}         
function enter(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        add();
    }
}            
function add(){
    if(input.value) {
        var novoLi = document.createElement('li');
        novoLi.addEventListener('click', feitoOuNao);
        novoLi.textContent = input.value;
        $List.appendChild(novoLi);
        addFocus();
    } else{
        addFocus();
        throw new Error('coloque um item válido')
    }                
    function addFocus(){
        input.focus();
        input.value = null;
    }
}
```

```css
.done{
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="addText">
<button>Adicionar Item</button>
<ol id="listContainer">
    <li>Varrer casa</li>
    <li>Lavar louça</li>
    <li>Fazer comida</li>
</ol>
```

---

## *Event delegation*

Se bem que para casos como esse, em que os elementos podem ser adicionados e você já quer que eles tenham determinado comportamento, uma alternativa melhor é usar *event delegation*.

A ideia básica é: em vez de setar um *listener* para cada `li` (tanto os existentes quanto os novos que surgirem depois), você seta um único *listener* para o elemento pai (no caso, o `ol`). E esse *listener* trata de verificar se um dos filhos foi clicado.

Isso funciona porque o evento de clique se propaga pelo DOM, então mesmo se o *listener* estiver no pai, é possível verificar se um dos filhos (e qual deles) foi clicado. Para mais detalhes, veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333053/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/534998/112052) e [aqui](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

Desta forma, você não precisa mais adicionar um novo *listener* para cada elemento criado, podendo inclusive voltar a usar `innerHTML` (mas ainda acho interessante ler [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8461851)).

Então ficaria assim (e também aproveitei para mudar alguns nomes de variáveis):

```js
var addItemButton = document.querySelector('button');
addItemButton.addEventListener('click', add);

var input = document.getElementById('addText');
input.addEventListener('keyup', enter);

var ol = document.getElementById('listContainer');
ol.addEventListener('click', feitoOuNao);

function feitoOuNao(event){
    let target = event.target; // elemento que foi clicado
    if (target.tagName != 'LI') // se não foi um li, não me interessa
        return;
    target.classList.toggle('done');
}         
function enter(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        add();
    }
}            
function add(){
    if (input.value){
        ol.innerHTML += '<li>'+ input.value +'</li>';
        addFocus();
    } else {
        addFocus();
        throw new Error('coloque um item válido');
    }                
}
function addFocus(){
    input.focus();
    input.value = null;
}
```

```css
.done {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="addText">
<button>Adicionar Item</button>
<ol id="listContainer">
    <li>Varrer casa</li>
    <li>Lavar louça</li>
    <li>Fazer comida</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: https://software.codidact.com/posts/284379/284386#answer-284386 é a sua própria resposta, mas nesses sites *"clones"*, eu não sou contra usar esses links, mas é redundância fazer dessa forma. O ideal é focar no original e evitar sites artificiais. Obs: a pergunta aqui é basicamente uma duplicata, só que a qualidade compromete o "status de qualidade", o que seria melhor apenas votar para fechar e no campo de comentário poderia adicionar a sua resposta de 2021, que parece que cobre todos os pontos necessários.

Answer (score -4):

Você vai precisar criar mais uma função:

```
function addListEvent() {
    $lis = $List.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(var i=0; i<$lis.length; i++){
        $lis[i].addEventListener('click', feitoOuNao);
    }
}
```

Depois, você só precisa executá-la dentro da função `add()`:

```
function add(){
    if(input.value){
        $List.innerHTML += '<li>'+ input.value +'</li>';
        addFocus();
        addListEvent() // <--- aqui
    else{
        addFocus();
        throw new Error('coloque um item válido')
    }                
    function addFocus(){
        input.focus();
        input.value = null;
    }
}
```

Seu código atual não tá funcionando porquê o `for` que executa o `addEventListener` nunca é executado depois que você adiciona um novo elemento nela. Além de que, mesmo que executasse, a variável `$lis` estaria desatualizada, não contendo o novo elemento que você adicionou.
Sendo assim, a função `addListEvent()` vai atualizar sua `$lis` e rodar o `for()` logo após.

Comment: O problema é que `addEventListener` é "acumulativo", então cada vez que adicionar um novo `li`, vc tb está adicionando mais um listener nos já existentes. Pra casos assim seria melhor usar event delegation: https://javascript.info/event-delegation